# How many elements are there in $\Bbb Z_5[i]/\langle 1+i\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory

> How many elements are there in  $\Bbb Z_5[i]/\langle 1+i\rangle$?

Any element of  $\Bbb Z_5[i]/\langle 1+i\rangle$ is of the form $a+bi+ \langle 1+i\rangle$

Now $1+i=0\implies i=-1\implies 2=0$

$a+bi+ \langle 1+i\rangle=a-b+ \langle 1+i\rangle$.

Since $2=0$ so we can take $a-b$ to be odd (say $1$)and hence the only elements are $  \langle 1+i\rangle,1+ \langle 1+i\rangle$

and hence $\Bbb Z_5[i]/\langle 1+i\rangle\cong \Bbb Z_2$

Is the solution correct?
Please help

Comment: Not only is $2=0$ but also $5=0$. Any other numbers that are zero.

Comment: Why does $i = -1\implies 2 = 0$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown; they are the only ones

Comment: Really? I would have thought that $7=2+5$ was zero as well...

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown; $7\equiv 2$  so ?How is it different

Comment: By $\Bbb Z_5[i]$, do you mean the quotient ring $\Bbb Z_5[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$, or just a (in hindsight, "the") subring of $\overline{\Bbb Z_5}$ obtained by adding an element $i$ such that $i^2=-1$ to $\Bbb Z_5$? Because, since $x^2+1=(x-3)(x-2)$, the former would be isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_5\times\Bbb Z_5$, and the latter would just be $\Bbb Z_5$ itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $2=0$, then $1=0$, since $1 = 2 + 2 + 2\;$in $Z_5$.

It follows that the quotient ring is the zero ring (so has only one element).

Said differently, the ideal $(1+i)$ contains $2$, since $(1+i)(1-i)=2$, hence contains $1$, since $1 = 2 + 2 + 2\;$in $Z_5$, so the ideal $(1+i) = (1)$, which is the full ring.

Answer (score 0):

The polynomial $X^2+1$ has roots in $\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z$: 
$\;\pm2$. Hence $\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z[i]=\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z$,  and as $1+i=1\pm 2\ne 0$, it is invertible  in the field$\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z$, so
$$(1+i)\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z[i]=\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z,\enspace\text{hence}\quad\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z[i]/(1+i)=\{0\}.$$